# Map files in sub directory to root folder via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a large number of files in a sub directory.  I would like to map these files to the root directory such that the request for "http://www.mysite.com/filename" actually points to "http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/filename.php" on the server.  I would like to remove the reference to the sub-folder.

Note that I'd like to append the "php" suffix in the htaccess file as well.  I also have a relatively large number of files in the root directory (including About, Contact, etc.) and a couple other folders so Rewrite Base is not a viable option.

Ideally, for each request, I would to test whether or not the file exists in the root folder, and if not, then map to the subfolder. I tried the following but could not map a file to a subfolder, let alone check if it exists first.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# works fine if not commented:
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
# try pointing to subfolder instead does not work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1.php
```

Thanks for any advice.  Plan B is to simply leave the folder name in the URL but I would be thrilled to find a more elegant solution and a shorter, more direct URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd rewrite condition will not work because you are not looking inside "folder", try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/folder%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1.php
```

If your document root was something like `/htdocs` then you were checking if the file `/htdocs/filename.php` exists when I think what you want is to check if `/htdocs/folder/filename.php` exists.